# Cross Browser Text Gradient & Stroke

Tags: css

I need to get a title with gradient and a stroke of 3px. I don't care if it is with png or not. I need cross Browser.

Code:

```
.title {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    /*
        This code gives me the gradient but only in Safari & Chrome. I need IE & Firefox to.
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffcc02), to(#fffe42));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;*/
}
```

Also i need to add a stroke. but outside no inside. Or if its inside which will be my new font-size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered this sort of question before, [check the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text/4919231#4919231).

> There is an experimental webkit property called text-stroke in CSS3,
> I've been trying to get this to work for some time but have been
> unsuccessful so far.
>
> What I have done instead is used the already supported text-shadow
> property (supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE 9 I believe).
>
> Use four shadows to simulate a stroked text:
>
> HTML:
>
> ```
> <div class="strokeme">
>     This text should have a stroke in some browsers
> </div>
> ```
>
> CSS:
>
> ```
> .strokeme
> {
>     color: white;
>     text-shadow:
>     -1px -1px 0 #000,
>     1px -1px 0 #000,
>     -1px 1px 0 #000,
>     1px 1px 0 #000;
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi kyle. That works awesome, but only in 1px. 3px got problems. And i need 3px. Also down´t work with the text gradient. But thanks :D