# How to make letters appear as they do in this wireframe?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have this wireframe that I am working from:

http://comehike.com/MOCKUP3.png

and on the top banner there are two sections like "find a hike" and "plan a hike"

How can I make letters like that? They are white, but have a brown layer around them. I am not sure how to do that.

Also, what font is that? Is it supported by most browsers?

Comment: That font looks like Arial Rounded MT Bold. It's supported by any browser as long as it's installed on the user's computer.

Comment: The css property used on the text to create that effect could be a `text-shadow` try it and see.

Comment: Either create it as an image or try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text

Comment: @interstellar: no you can't, it doesn't have the expand property like the box-shadow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a css3 property called text-stroke which does exactly the same thing you asked. The easiest cross-browser solution would be an image.

More on text-stroke: http://www.cardeo.ca/2010/adding-an-outline-to-your-text-using-the-css3-text-stroke-property

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider `<canvas>` to show-off your Bezier talent :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a stroke to look like that with pure CSS. Unfortunately, that is a a photoshop effect and you won't be able to do that with live text.

Same goes for up in the nav. That looks like a bezel effect, so you'll have to recreate that with an image.