# text-stroke cross browser

Tags: css

I'm trying the new text-stroke features and I've searched the web for a cross browser solution. For now I only could find it with webkit properties.

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #FF1E00;
```

Could you let me know if there is a way so all browsers will display in the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of May 24<sup>th</sup>, 2012, there is no cross-browser solution, as only webkit supports the experimental feature according to http://caniuse.com/#search=text-stroke. You can simulate this (to some degree) with 4 or 5 `text-shadow`'s on an element.

Demo: [Text Stroke](http://css-tricks.com/examples/TextStroke/), on CSS-Tricks.com

Answer (score 11):

```
.strokeme
{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 0 #000,
    1px -1px 0 #000,
    -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;  
}
```

from: [Outline effect to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text)

"What I have done instead is used the already supported text-shadow property (supported in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE 9 I believe)."

Answer (score 1):

You could try [strokeText.js](https://inorganik.github.io/strokeText.js/), a vanilla javascript plugin.

- Strokes do not overlap your text like they do with
  `-webkit-text-stroke`
- Supports all browsers except IE8 and below
- Selectable text
- Dependency-free

Full disclosure, I made the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done natively cross-browser, but it can be implemented with a fallback for unsupported browsers:

```
color: blue;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: blue;
-webkit-text-fill-color: white;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
```

That way, webkit browsers will display white text with blue outline, but other browsers will still display the color of your choosing (this case blue).