# How can I add a border on my text in css/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, I want to add a border on my text with html, css or javascript. the size of the border should be 10px. Is this possible?

So it should be like this:
[image]

Hope you can help,

regards
chris

Comment: You can do that with CSS3, but this feature is experimental. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text and http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text

Comment: There's currently no CSS property which allows for text to be styled with stroke. You could achieve this using SVG, a web-safe font (or a web font).

Comment: I cannot see the picture. you should try { display: inline-block; border: 10px solid black; }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said, you could try this with `text-shadow`, but it is not recommended. I edited Ankit's solution, because it looked aliased:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnfED/1409/

```
text-shadow: 2px 0 black, -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 0 -2px black, 1px 1px black, -1px -1px black, -1px 1px black, 1px -1px black;
```

As Eric Brockman says, you could use [`text-stroke`](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/), but this is currently **not supported** by most browsers. It works on `-webkit-` prefixed browsers though.

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnfED/1410/

```
   -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

Note that `-webkit-text-fill-color` will always overwrite `color`, no matter what the order is in your CSS.

Comment: the first result with the text-shadow looks really great, and unfortunately the second one's border is inner-border

Comment: @user1836363 Then you should use the first one. :) Yes, `text-stroke` is an inner stroke. You can try to 'bypass' this by using `font-weight`.

Answer (score 2):

You require lot of shadows, more the number of shadows better is the effect

```
{
    font-size:80px;
    color: green;
   text-shadow: 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black, 0 0 4px black;
}
```

Here is the link to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnfED/1408/
you can increase/decrease the width of shadow by using any other value in text-shadow property (where i have used 4px)

**NOTE : This is supported by only a few browsers**

I'll suggest you to use image instead of this because you will not need to bother about browser compatibility

Comment: And images will only increase traffic and page load. We don't want to use images.

Comment: it totally depends on number of images if its a huge number of images then only it will make a difference as these will be vector images and will be considerably small in size

Comment: It will **always** affect page load more heavily than CSS would.

Comment: sorry but i cant use images because the text is variable

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your style sheet:

```
h1 {
   color: black;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

Read more about this option here: http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on experimental features, I suggest you create a transparent .PNG image that looks like the one you've posted, create a `div` with the necessary text and width, then set the `text-indent` property to `-9999px` in CSS. Set the PNG image as the background of the `div` using the background property. and you will have successfully used the `-9999px` hack.

See here: http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2007/09/01/css-hack-text-indent-10000px/ This is what Apple uses to create beautiful typography on their website.

Comment: As you can see, that's a post from 2007. It's 2013 alright! It's time we, as developers, start using new techniques and - if necessary - use fallbacks. Innovation is the future, lagging behind will only cause the industry to fall as well.

Comment: @BramVanroy 2013 or not, there are a whole bunch of (l)users using Internet Explorer. Nothing can be said about them

Comment: That's why I mentioned fallbacks. :)