# Fonts with different color outline, for web

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is it possible to have transparent or non-transparent font with different color outline with just HTML5 and CCS3? How?

Comment: Ok. I just found few google webfonts. One is http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Londrina+Shadow. Still, can I do it with default fonts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outline effect to text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`text-stroke` property](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/), which does exactly that.
Beware that it's [only supported by WebKit](http://caniuse.com/text-stroke).

You can also [fake it with `text-shadow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919231/34397).

Answer (score 0):

Using the text-shadow property it is possible:

EDIT: Now it's uniform. Play around with the values to achieve different results.

http://jsfiddle.net/qE2ev/1/

```
span {
    color:white;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black,
  1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```