# Add white outline around text block

Tags: css

Need to add straight white outline around text (without blur effect like in text-shadow).
Example:

[image: http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_3406166_9096951.png]

Comment: You are going to need to elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Don't forget to post the code that shows what you've tried already.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a text shadow? That's the way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outline effect to text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text)

Comment: thanks for the last comment, i found it the best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple text shadows.

```
text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #fff, -2px 0 0 #fff, 0 2px 0 #fff, 0 -2px 0 #fff, 1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff;
```

[read more details on this](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)

Comment: Thanks, it's very close. I think i need to change px parametres to get more smooth background.

Comment: unfortunately i have a low reputation for voting cause i'm beginner

Answer (score 0):

There is `text-stroke`, but unfortunately it's webkit only.

```
.text_class {
   -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}
```

It comes with a fallback though so it's safe to use if you don't mind it reverting in FF/Opera/IE.

```
.text-class {
   color: black;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

CSS-Tricks has more info on `text-stroke` [here](http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/).