# Making transparent text in CSS and fitting background image inside a text shape

Tags: html, css

CSS color has no transparent input that is they are all solid. So I tried to set opacity using rgba for the color property but the image background is not showing through the text.  Is there a way to do this?  So there a background image and heavy text on top that needs to be transparent only showing the letters outline.

I wish to have result like on example [dank.sh](https://dank.sh)

Comment: Can you show some code of what you’ve tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a text stroke with transparent text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050556/how-to-make-a-text-stroke-with-transparent-text)

Comment: Can you elaborate your tries using `opacity` if any?

Comment: @Tecnogirl no, I don't want to use SVG.

Comment: yes I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835500/how-to-change-text-transparency-in-html-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
element.style {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0); /* for transparent color */
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0,0,0,1.0); /* for solid black outline */
}
```

**UPDATED**

If you need background image though the text:

```css
.bg-though-text {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0B2349 33%, #0D61BC 66%, #8AA9D6); /* Here you can use an image bg */
  
    /* This will start the magic */

    -webkit-background-clip: text; /* This will bring bg shape according to text*/
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* This will make text color transparent */
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0); /* This will make text color transparent for sure */
}
```

```html
<p class="bg-though-text">Gradient bg</p>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Transparent text, white bg and image behind.

```css
.bg {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #a50026, #d3322b, #f16d43, #fcab64, #fedc90, #faf8c0, #dcf1ec, #abd6e8, #76abd0, #4a74b4, #4a74b4);
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.transparent-text {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;  
    padding: 5px 10px;
  
  /* Here we go */

    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <p class="transparent-text">Transparent text</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 3**

An SVG solution, IE11 supports:

```css
.bg {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #a50026, #d3322b, #f16d43, #fcab64, #fedc90, #faf8c0, #dcf1ec, #abd6e8, #76abd0, #4a74b4, #4a74b4);
    padding:20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 60">
        <defs>
            <g id="text">
                <text text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="23" font-size="12">Transtarent text</text>
            </g>
            <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50">
                 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" fill="#fff"/>
                 <use xlink:href="#text" />
           </mask>
       </defs>
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="90" height="30" mask="url(#mask)"  fill="#fff" fill-opacity="1"/>
 </svg>
 </div>
```

Comment: I need the text framed in white background, then underneath the image, like in dank.sh link I gave.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode - it supports Edge. for IE - sorry, you will have to use simple png image. nothing we can do there. all modern browsers will work fine. glad to help you

Comment: This solution is valid enough to have an article here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cutout_text.asp

Comment: Updated an SVG solution for you. But I suggest to use mix-blend-mode: screen;

Comment: Thanks focus style, your update 2 works for me since it also works with Edge, IE is no longer important.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is your friend:

```css
#id {
    opacity: 0.5; // For 50% opacity
}
```

Comment: opacity is making my whole div container transparent I only need the letters or text trasnparent like this https://dank.sh/.

Comment: You need to adjust opacity of the element which contains text. If you have text directly in your container div, just put the text in another div without background and adjust opacity of that

Comment: I did that but the white background need to be opaque like in the dank.sh example, only the letters need to be transparent.

Comment: The dank.sh example uses SVG, which would be the most cross-browser compatible thing to do. Otherwise you could look into `-webkit-background-clip` property, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's not widely supported.

Comment: So you can create the text in any vector-based software, and export SVG code for it

Answer (score 0):

```
.text {
    opacity: 0.7; /* Can be varied to the transparency you want */
}
```

The `opacity` will change the text transparency.