# i have a font with out line but i want to fill color in it with css. it is possible to fill color in it

Tags: css

I am trying to create outlined texted using [this batman font](http://www.dafont.com/batman-forever.font), like below:

[image]

How can I do this using CSS?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsOvc.png

Comment: here is the font http://www.dafont.com/batman-forever.font

Comment: Hi Sumer. Welcome to stack overflow. You can edit your post to include the images in your post.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919076/outline-effect-to-text

Answer (score 1):

The font itself having outerline so,  you just add color to text, you just add `color:red;` for your outline font.

For Example:

```
<h1 style="font-family: myFirstFont; color:green;">FONT <span style="color:red;"> COLOR</span></h1>
```

Your result  [Here what you are looking for](http://demos.sanwebcorner.com/fill-color-to-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't fill color through css3 in font

> use text shadow

see this:

> [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfgHV.jpg)

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<style>
body{font-family:BatmanForeverAlternate;color:#333333;font-size:48px;text-shadow: -1px 0 #ff0000, 0 1px #ff0000, 1px 0 #ff0000, 0 -1px #ff0000;}
p span{color:#ff0000;text-shadow: -1px 0 #333333, 0 1px #333333, 1px 0 #333333, 0 -1px #333333;}
</style>
<body>
<p>T<span>A</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the stroke of a letter you can use [text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke), please note this property is not supported on IE.

Alternatively you could use SVG.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px gray;
}
h1 > span {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px red;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>T</span>A</h1>
```