# Convering variable Google Fonts to static fonts due to variable font text-stroke issues

Tags: fonts, google-fonts, ttx-fonttools

There are some documented issues with Google Fonts where specifically many variable fonts don't play with with -webkit-text-stroke.

The font that is discussed primarily on github et al. is Montserrat and while someone did provide some static Montserrat files as a quick fix, I am finding there are many more fonts with this issue beyond just that one.

The text renders with little cross lines all over the words (see picture).

While I understand there are other ways to attempt to create text-strokes, they won't work for me, so not looking to re-invent the wheel as far as the CSS part goes.

[image: Certain Fonts have cross-lines in them when adding -webkit-text-stroke]

The solution seems to be to just self-host the static versions of the fonts.

However, I have tried to find where to download the static versions of the fonts, but they don't seem to be available via Google Fonts.

I have read others post about merging contours of the variable font which I guess means making it static again?  Is there a tool out there where you can just convert the variable font to static or perform this "countour merge?"

Or is there a way to download the static versions from Google and I just don't know it?  (note I don't mean a static URL, I mean the static version of the font.)

Comment: That's a WebKit bug: it should. be detecting the contour overlaps and providing an outline of the glyph without the overlaps. Merging contours is not the same as deriving a static instance font, though there might be some tool out that removes overlaps when deriving a static instance.

Comment: @PeterConstable Thanks for commenting Peter.  When I wrote this I was confused mainly because I downloaded the static fonts as many have suggested and they do have the same issue.  Had me wondering what made a font static and variable.  I assume now that if I download the Montserrat 800 font it must be static as a variable font is all one single file right?

Comment: A variable font has glyph outline data as well as other delta data describing ways that the glyph outlines can change. A variable font also has an 'fvar' table that specifies one or more axes of design variation, with numeric ranges for each axis. When a value for each axis is selected, then a specific instance of the variable is selected. When I referred to "deriving a static instance", that means selecting an instance and then exporting the resulting glyph outlines. If the default outlines have overlaps, then the outlines for a specific instance probably also have the same overlaps.

Comment: Yes, a variable font is a single file.

Comment: @PeterConstable Yeah, now I understand it.  What was confusing me was when I switched to the static font, it didn't make any difference, so I was rather confused as others said using the static font would resolve the overlapping issue.  That still has me confused.  However,  I ended up going with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#73226502  which I thought could be dicey, but turns out it works pretty well.  Thanks again for your help.