# Using special characters within Javascript data-attributes for CSS ::after content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this solution:

[Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#73226502)

To solve an issue where certain fonts do not display the -webkit-text-stroke properly.

The solution involves overlaying an CSS ::after tag with basically a copy of the text to cover up the inconsistencies.

Here is an example:

```css
.test {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 60px !important;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5.75px rgb(255,9,0) !important;
    background-color: null;
    text-shadow: 1.68px 1.68px rgb(255 208 130);
    text-transform: inherit !important;
    top: 0px;
    position:relative;
    }
    
    
    .test::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-text="Pickles">
Pickles
</div>
```

This works fine until a quote is put into the attribute which will break it.

Here is what happens when you add a quote:

```css
.test {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 60px !important;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5.75px rgb(255,9,0) !important;
    background-color: null;
    text-shadow: 1.68px 1.68px rgb(255 208 130);
    text-transform: inherit !important;
    top: 0px;
    position:relative;
    }
    
    
    .test::after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-text=""Pickles">
"Pickles
</div>
```

How can I add a quote into the data attribute or any other special characters for that matter so that the CSS will read it properly?

I have tried escaping it and I have tried to use encodeURI(); but neither of these is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Write it using `&quot;` (called [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity))

```css
.test {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 60px !important;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5.75px rgb(255, 9, 0) !important;
  background-color: null;
  text-shadow: 1.68px 1.68px rgb(255 208 130);
  text-transform: inherit !important;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.test::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-shadow: none;
  top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-text="&quot;Pickles">
  "Pickles
</div>
```