# Text-stroke goes through itself while using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

EDIT: A similar post has already been made: [Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#69937834)

I am having a very strange problem with a text on a website I am working on. This was not happening before, and I did not change anything, but one day I loaded the website and noticed the text stroke I applied was going through itself (see image). I am using Tailwind CSS. Here is the code for the element

[The letter's a and e are cutting through themselves.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKspi.png)

Code for the element:

```html
<h1 className="text-7xl text-white text-stroke-3 text-center mt-5 font-bold">
          How are you feeling today? 
</h1>
```

Also this text-stroke is a custom CSS property that I defined as follows:

```css
.text-stroke-3 {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
}
```

I tried changing the h1 to a paragraph and changing the font of the text. I also tried using

```html
<b></b>
```

to encapsulate the text instead of `font-bold`.
None of these worked.

Comment: I think you have changed the font style in a parent element and it impacts this element. Inspect that element and be sure it is not because of a new font.

Comment: Probably you're using a variable font. See this post: ["Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#69937834) for workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar post has been made already:
[Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#69937834)

It seems that the main problem is with webkit text stroke itself being inconsistent. I solved this problem by using a different font.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the  problem is caused by the `-webkit-text-stroke` property, which is not supported by all browsers, and may cause issues with some fonts.

You could instead use a text shadow.

```
.text-stroke-3 {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
}
```

This creates four text shadows around the text, which will give the appearance of a `stroke`. You can adjust the size of the stroke by changing the values of the `text-shadow` property.

Comment: Interesting solution, but there is still some noticeable visual oddities around the text with the shadows. Also I am using chrome so my browser shouldn't be the issue.