# The svg text animation looks different in some mobile devices

Tags: html, css, github, svg, software-design

I tried to add a svg animation text to my webpage and hosted it to a github webpage.But when i open it in some mobile devices the text animation looks different.
Here is what is expected
[Expected Text Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHCeo.png)
But in some mobile phones it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHMn.png)
It only occurs in some mobile devices.

Here is the html and css of the text
**html**

```
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1650 400">
            <text x="50%" y="70%" fill="transparent" text-anchor="middle">
                TECHNE
            </text>
     </svg>
```

**css**

```
    svg text{
        font-size: 7rem;
        stroke: #0ed1c1;
        font-size: 9rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        stroke-width: 5;
        animation: textAnimate 5s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes textAnimate{
        0%{
            stroke-dasharray: 0 50%;
        }
        100%{
            stroke-dasharray: 50% 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: That's indeed strange and is similar to this [`text-stroke` rendering bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#69937834) related to variable fonts. So as a workaround, try to replace the font with a static (non-variable)  font. Please add more details which mobile browsers are affected