# SVG text not aligning to HTML text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

Why does absolutely positioned SVG Text not fully line up with the exact same CSS text? It's awkwardly offset. Any insight into this would be great!

I have `x: 50%` and the relevant `text-anchor` prop configured to `middle` but this does not seem to properly centre the text in the SVG container.

note: reason for this is to use SVG text outline functionality (full outline does not look good with text-shadow).

Showcasing this problem:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <div>TextasdasdTasdadasd</div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50%" y="55%" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">TextasdasdTasdadasd</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

In the image the red text is SVG and black text is HTML.

[image: Red text (SVG) not aligned to black text (HTML)]

Comment: The horizontal alignment looks fine in chrome and firefox. You need to tweak the y/dy values to get the vertical alignment right as svg text elements ignore the line height property

Comment: I see - it doesn't work in safari/webkit. I'm afraid svg `<text>` still has too many rendering inconsistencies across different browsers. If your ultimate goal is to get a better text stroke you might try  [Luke Taylor's approach: "Text Stroke (-webkit-text-stroke) css Problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253420/text-stroke-webkit-text-stroke-css-problem/69937834#73146972)

Answer (score 1):

It is centered, your wrapper is juste bigger than you think i adapt the width of the container to the full width so you can have a look

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">
  <div>TextasdasdTasdadasd</div>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="50%" y="55%" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">TextasdasdTasdadasd</text>
  </svg>
</div>
```