# Constantly inverting text based on the element behind it

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble coding my navbar that is fixed to the bottom of the page. The navbar is simply text without a background color and since it passes through many different colours the idea was to have the text on the navbar invert so that it is visible no matter what image/object is beneath it.

I can't seem to figure it out with HTML and CSS. I've tried mix-blend-mode.

Here is the basic code for the navbar.
HTML

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    padding: 1rem;
}

ul li a {
    color: var(--black);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: There's is no relation to either Java/Javascript in the code you have posted. And both are different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mix-blend-mode` `difference` and `exclusion` work for me in most use cases.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2%;
  right: 2%;
  z-index: 1000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul li a {
  color: var(--black);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    white 0px,
    red 400px,
    green 600px,
    yellow 800px,
    blue 1000px,
    cyan 1200px,
    magenta 1400px,
    black 1600px
  );
  height: 1800px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Another strategy you can have to make sure your text is always visible whatever the background is to use multiple text shadows like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919231/12571484) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works almost exactly how i want it to work in your demo, but when I input it into my site it doesn't. Is it possible that it only can detect the colour of other css elements and not images? My body is simply white so the nav text is just black. Can you get the same effect when the nav bar is going over images or is that not possible?

Comment: It works for `background-image` and `img` too.

Comment: I have no idea why its not working then. Is there any idea you can give me without me pasting my whole website in this chat lol.

Comment: Put a link to the site in the comment below and I'll have a look

Comment: You've set the colour of the nav text in two places. You've set it white in the `a` selector and then black a little bit further down in the `ul li a` selector. Black on mix-blend-mode: difference` rule just disappears.  Hope this helps.